# Is the caffeine in coffee an oxidation agent?

Tags: home-experiment

I heard a friend say:

> You have to watch out for coffee, the caffeine is an oxidation agent.

Now I remember [carbon Chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidation_of_primary_alcohols_to_carboxylic_acids) from year 12.

[image]

You can oxidise ethanol to ethanal, and then to ethanoic acid.

But I don't understand how this would apply to [caffeine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine).

[image]

My question is: **Is the caffeine in coffee an oxidation agent?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, caffeine is not known as an oxidizing agent.

Comment: Guess it could oxidize $\ce{LiAlH4}$ or something of the sort, but in any case this has absolutely nothing to do whatsoever with the health hazard it presents.

Comment: Yeah it could be made to lose its oxygen or electrons but couldn't any compound containing oxygen? I think because it doesn't do this readily in normal conditions like H2O2 or another common oxidizing agent it is not classed as an oxidizing agent. I was going to add that in the answer but thought it would go off topic.